# Regex (php) to match single [ or single ] but ignore anything between [[ ]]?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regexp-replace

I have a string, and within it there will be combinations of [ ]  [[  ]] ][ but I need to replace the single [ and ] with < and > but leave alone (don't match) anything that is between [[ ]].

I thought I could do this with a regex, but I'm really struggling to get it to work because the complexity is just beyond me at the moment.

Example string:

```
[a] [b]  <- should replace every [ with < and every ] with > so <a> <b>

[a][b]   <- should replace every [ with < and every ] with > so <a><b>

[[abc][a][b]]  <- should not replace anything. will always start with [[ and end with ]]
```

So thinking about this logically, I can do it in a loop with PHP but I really want to try and use a  preg_replace if possible.

The logic, as far as I can decipher is to replace [ with < and ] with > EXCEPT between a [[ and ]] but I'm not sure if I can even do that in a regex. I can make it work partially by using lookahead/lookbehind but that still then matches [ and ] between [[ and ]] (e.g. [[ [a] ]].

So far I've got

```
    /(?<!(^|)\[)\[[^\]\[\[]*\]/gmi
```

Working to spot [a] but not [[a]] but fails if I have [[a [b] c]].
At this point I'm not worried about the replacement, I just need to get the regex working to match / not match.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `g` as a modifier won't work in PHP. Please provide code you are using.

Comment: In the future you should provide regex101 links so we can work with what you are working with. I think https://regex101.com/r/PjCOes/1 achieves your goal

Comment: Or this one: [`\[([^][]*)\]|\[(?:[^][]*(?R)?)*+\](*SKIP)(*F)`](https://regex101.com/r/W8aiso/2)

Comment: If you **don't** have mixed strings, a [`\G` based](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) idea: [`\G[^][]*\K\[([^][]*)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/gsU4t1/1) (this is a bit more efficient and worth to be mentioned if you *don't* have strings like e.g. `[[a][b]] [a][b]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~(\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|]]).|(?1))*]])(*SKIP)(*F)|\[([^][]*)]~s', '<$2>', $text)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/3CamQ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zrpzi2/1).

*Details*:

- `(\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|]]).|(?1))*]])(*SKIP)(*F)` - Group 1: `[[`, zero or more occurrences of any char that is not a starting point of the `[[` or `]]` char sequences or the whole Group 1 pattern recursed, and then `]]`, and once the match is found, it is skipped, the new search starts at the failure location
- `|` - or
- `\[([^][]*)]` - a `[`, then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` captured into Group 2, and then a `]`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, that is absolutely perfect and I now see how *SKIP works which I just couldn't get my head around.